# Unsupported concurrent change during composition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Anyone please advise what I can do this.  I do have a state variable that is updated in the composition and elsewhere.  Do I need a lock to ensure that it is not changed at the same time?

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported concurrent change during composition. A state object was modified by composition as well as being modified outside composition.
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.applyAndCheck(Recomposer.kt:825)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1092)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:105)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:456)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:425)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1090)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15089 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you, read about side effects.
I think you should use one of this rememberCoroutineScope , LaunchedEffect..

Read more:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects